# Swal Fire Input Select from array

Tags: angular

Hello I want to make a fire popup with a select input.
But I'm not able to show my data from my array .

Array :

```
this.list = [
{
    "vpsId": "06BD0509ADBF3AFE585647C326C68844",
    "vpsIp": "52.5.5.5"
},
{
    "vpsId": "07097478F287D91BC68F7908AC8797FA",
    "vpsIp": "45.234.354"
},
{
    "vpsId": "6BB3415CAB1EDBC9D18D401C2C615A72",
    "vpsIp": "104.144.111.71"
}
];
```

And there is the code that I use to open Swail

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Select one',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: new Map([
this.list
]),
  inputValue: '1',
  showCancelButton: true
});
```

I got two row in my select there is :
06BD0509ADBF3AFE585647C326C68844
52.5.5.5

But I want to get :

```
<option value="vpsId">vpsIp</option>
```

Thanks

Or if is it possible like this :

```
  title: "<i>Title</i>", 
  html: '<select> <option *ngFor="let i of this.list [value]="i.vpsId">i.vpsIp</option></select>' ,  
  confirmButtonText: "Fermer", 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpe ngFor

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let i of items" [value]="i.vpsId">{{i.vpsIp}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hello , I want to use the input Select of Swa.fire